# send file in chat objective -c

Tags: objective-c, attachment, http-method

I have a chat App in objective-c, that for now just sends message, certainly the server support to upload the file and send file in chat, but I don't know how to implement in my chat the attachment to send. Is there any tutorial in objective-c to see how they did?

Comment: Since we have no idea which technology your chat client uses how are we to know how a send file? Also asking for tutorials is offtopic, please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Steven, your question seems too broad to me